Implementing dynamic product details with compulsory items in e-commerce site
I'm developing an e-commerce site using Next.js 14 with TypeScript and Tailwind CSS. I'm trying to implement a feature similar to what's seen on the Ubiquiti store for this product.
My requirement is to display a main product alongside its compulsory or related products on the same page. The key features I'm looking to implement are:

Show the main product details.
Display a list of compulsory products associated with the main
product.
Allow users to click on compulsory products to view their details
without navigating away from the page but update the URL to the
selected product's URL.
If the user refreshes the page, it should load the details of the
product corresponding to the current URL.
The layout should remain similar to the Ubiquiti site, where
compulsory products are listed below the main product, and clicking
on them updates the product details while keeping the list visible.


Each product (main and compulsory) has its own set of data and can potentially be a main product on its own page with its own set of compulsory items.
I'm looking for guidance on the best way to structure this in Next.js 14.
Specifically:

How can I implement URL changes without full page reloads when selecting compulsory products?
What's the most efficient way to fetch and manage data for both the main product and its compulsory items?
How should I handle the initial load and subsequent updates to ensure the correct product is displayed based on the URL?

